# How do you apply CSS styles to a paragraph in RMarkdown?

Tags: css, r, r-markdown

I tried to use CSS styles in RMarkdown to change the colour of text, but it only works for a continuous paragraph and not multiple paragraphs.

```
<p style = "color:blue">
paragraph 1 here
</p>
```

```
<p style = "color:blue">
paragraph 1 here

paragraph 2 here
</p>
```

The first gives me blue text, but the second one doesn't. I don't really get why it doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: See Yihui's amazing book on [`rmarkdown`](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/html-css.html). It will guide you through (almost)  all problems related to R-markdown.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it didn't like the space in the `<p>` tag.  This works:

```
<p style="color:blue">
paragraph 1 here
</p>

<p style="color:blue">
paragraph 1 here
</br>
</br>
paragraph 2 here
</p>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As DaveArmstrong points out, the problem is with the blank line.  Rmarkdown allows raw html blocks to be embedded in a markdown document but the block must be surrounded by blank lines.  The blank line following paragraph 1 in your post marked the end the html block.  Markdown then ignored the `</p>` following the second paragraph.  Adding `<br>` between the paragraphs continues the html block so that markdown can properly match `<p>` tags.  See the Pandoc Users Manual [Pandoc User's Manual](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.pdf#:%7E:text=%20%20%20Title%20%20%20Pandoc%20User%27s,Created%20Date%20%20%207%2F23%2F2020%209%3A38%3A06%20PM%20) section on Raw HTML.

Markdown recognizes a backslash followed by the newline as a line break so you also could have used:

```
<p style = "color: blue;">
paragraph 1 here\
\
paragraph 2 here</p>
```

to give the two blue paragraphs.